# What is the best way of project's organization?

Tags: c++, c, pipe, project-organization

I need to develop a simple portable C++ program Billing_Unit. 
It reads some parameters (telefone number, etc.) and returns the price of call and rest of free minutes.

I decided to get data for Billing_Unit from standart input, and output result to standart output.

I developed two test units: Test_Unit_Source and Test_Unit_Destination.

I decided to organize a consecutive performing of my program units:

1. Test_Unit_Source: Reads data from database and puts it to
       standart output;
2. Billing_Unit: Reads standart output from
       previous unit, Calculates the call costs and the rest of free
       minutes, outputs result.
3. Test_Unit_Destination: Reads the call
       costs and the rest of free minutes, stores it to database.

   Test_Unit_Source | Billing_Unit | Test_Unit_Destination

Simplified Test_Unit_Source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#define SUCCESS_RESULT 0
#define ERROR_RESULT 1

using namespace std;

int main() {
    signed char buf;

    string Name_File;
    ifstream inp_file;

    inp_file.open("temp.txt",std::ios::binary);

    if (!inp_file) return ERROR_RESULT;

    do {
        buf=inp_file.get();
        cout<<buf;
    } while (!inp_file.eof());

    return SUCCESS_RESULT;
}
```

Simplified Billing_Unit - **it must be portable**:

```
#include <iostream>

#define SUCCESS_RESULT 0
#define ERROR_RESULT 1

int main() {
    signed char var;
    unsigned long res;//cents
    signed char next_call;

    while (!EOF_USERS) {
        std::cin >> input_data;
            ...
        //calculations
            ...
        std::cout << result;
    }

    std::cout << EOF_USERS;

    return SUCCESS_RESULT;
}
```

Simplified Test_Unit_Destination:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#define SUCCESS_RESULT 0
#define ERROR_RESULT 1

using namespace std;

int main() {
    signed char buf;

    ofstream out_file;

    out_file.open("out.txt",std::ios::binary);

    if (!out_file) return ERROR_RESULT;

    while (!EOF_USERS) {
        cin >> buf;
        out_file << buf;        
    }



    return SUCCESS_RESULT;
}
```

Actually Test_Unit_Source and Test_Unit_Destination can be united in one program unit. It depends on my decision.

Is it a good organization of my project?
What is the best organization of this project? May be it's better to set input parameters for Billing_Unit through command line, but I don't know how to return the result in this case.

Comment: For command-line arguments, try `int main (int argc, char *argv[])` This will give you each argument. You can check to see if there are none before asking for input.

Comment: those look like a functional tests (not unit tests)

Comment: chris, yes, you are quite right. I know how to get input data through command-line, but I don't know how to return the result. Compiler asks me to return only int type.

Comment: Not sure what exactly is the question, but looks like you want to have a file with expected results, with which you want to compare, and return ERROR_RESULT or SUCCESS_RESULT

Comment: Billing_Unit - is a main unit. I want to separate it from reading and writing from database. I'd like to develop a "box" that receives data, calculates something and returns result. It is preferable to use standart input and output for better performance. However, if there is no another solution of this problem I will have to write results to file.

Comment: Why the votes to close?  This question is an excellent demonstration of one of the fundamental strengths of `stdin`, `stdout`, and pipes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your design fits perfectly into the model of unix-like languages: by writing your program as a filter that reads `stdin` and writes to `stdout` you're giving users the flexibility to easily pre- or post-process the data.

For example, as you've written it, you can simply run

```
Billing_Unit < input_file > output_file
```

But suppose the input data is in the wrong format.  Then you can run

```
reformat_data < input_file | Billing_Unit > output_file
```

And you can change the output format with

```
Billing_Unit < input_file | sort_by_customer > output file
```

These are simple examples, but I hope they show you how easy it is to work with a program like yours.

If you do plan to run your program directly from the shell like this, be sure that any error messages are written to `stderr` instead of `stdout`.  That will separate them from your output data, so they won't be processed as input by the next command.

Comment: Such design fits for Unix OS and Windows for sure. Is such design suitable for other operational systems? My task is to develop a portable program.

Comment: In general, portability is more about avoiding OS-specific dependencies; your program falls into the "pure data" category so there's much less to worry about.  If you're uncomfortable using only `stdin` and `stdout` you could allow the user to specify optional file names on the command line.  If the names are given, use the files; if not, use `stdin` and `stdout` instead.  That way you've covered both possibilities.